# How to Transpose in the Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this in excel:

```
 P|A |R |T
--|--|--|
--|--|--|
--|--|--|
 P|G |--|
--|--|--|
 P|--|--|
```

I want like this:

```
P|--|--|
A|--|--|
R|--|--|
T|--|--|
P|--|--|
G|--|--|
P|--|--|
```

Comment: Your tables don't define the transformation you need. What do the `--` cells represent? Please explain in a lot more detail how you want the cells to be remapped.

Comment: -- use for blank spase only.

Answer (score 2):

**This simple UDF will Transpose the shown data with blank cells in between:**

```
Option Base 1
Function TranBlank(X As Range, Y As Long) As Variant
Dim RZArray() As String
Dim c As Range


i = 0
For Each c In X
    If Len(c) > 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve RZArray(i)
        RZArray(i) = c.Value
    End If
Next c


TranBlank = RZArray(Y)
End Function
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this code as Module with 
  related Sheet.
- Write this formula and fill down.
- Adjust cell references in formula as 
  needed.

  `=IFERROR(TranBlank(A$2:D$7,ROW(A1)),"")`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try Power Query to translate the Range.

Select the Range, go to Data- From Range and Table- in Power Query Editor select all columns- in Transform tab select Unpivot Columns- sort the Value and remove Column:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your example cannot be converted with one command. I hope you see it. Part of the table can be simply marked with mouse, ctrl-C (to copy) and right-click at the target position an chose "paste special". You see the dialog where you can find "transpose". As it is described [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/transpose.html).